# How to set a protected route in node.js? same as with the userRoutes.js that I have

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, jwt

How will I set a {protected} as the first argument in my router.route('/').get(protect, getProducts)
I am trying to protect my '/' route same as the
router.route('/profile').get(protect, getUserProfile)

[Here is my authMiddleware.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zO8E.png)

[productController.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxnC9.png)

[productRoutes.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc7jH.png)

These are my users files in which I use the same middleware:

[This is my userRoutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEojr.png)

This is my userRoutes.js below:

```
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import generateToken from '../utils/generateToken.js'
import User from '../models/userModel.js'

// @desc    Auth user & get token
// @route   POST /api/users/login
// @access  Public
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
const { email, password } = req.body

const user = await User.findOne({ email })

if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
res.json({
  _id: user._id,
  name: user.name,
  email: user.email,
  isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
  token: generateToken(user._id),
  })
  } else {
  res.status(401)
  throw new Error('Invalid email or password')
  }
  })

  // @desc    Register a new user
  // @route   POST /api/users
  // @access  Public
  const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body

  const userExist = await User.findOne({ email })

  if (userExist) {
  res.status(400)
  throw new Error('User already exists')
  }

  const user = await User.create({
  name,
  email,
  password,
  })

  if (user) {
  res.status(201).json({
  _id: user._id,
  name: user.name,
  email: user.email,
  isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
  token: generateToken(user._id),
  })
  } else {
  res.status(400)
  throw new Error('Invalid user data')
  }
  })

  // @desc    Get user profile
  // @route   GET /api/users/profile
  // @access  Private
  const getUserProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id)

  if (user) {
  res.json({
  _id: user._id,
  name: user.name,
  email: user.email,
  isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
  })
  } else {
  res.status(404)
  throw new Error('User not found')
  }
  })

  export { authUser, registerUser, getUserProfile }
```

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Comment: can you say what do you want exactly??do you want protect middleware in your route?

Comment: Could the question be narrowed? Is this the minimal code you need to reproduce the problem? By doing it you may find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like :

```
router.get('/', [protect], getProducts);
```

Calling your middleware and simplifying syntax :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still have problems when showing it in my screen I think it has something to do with jwt and stuff. I'll update my question with the user example :)